# NoSuchElementException despite using hasNext

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I keep getting the NoSuchElementException despite checking using hasNext. Basically, I want to only read integers that are being passed into the scanner. My loop runs while the next Readable is not an integer. When it is, the integer is returned.

```java
int handleIntVal(Scanner scan) {
    while (!scan.hasNextInt()) {
        scan.next();
    }
    return scan.nextInt();
}
```

Comment: I ran your code but It seems okay.

Comment: @Alif Hasnian Weird. Thank for the quick response, though

Answer (score 0):

A `NoSuchElementException` will be thrown already by `scan.next()` if there is no next element. As you are not checking for `hasNext()` but for `!hasNext()` there is no guard to this.

I didn't try but this should work:

```
int handleIntVal(Scanner scan) {
    while (scan.hasNext() && !scan.hasNextInt()) {
        scan.next();
    }
    if (scan.hasNext()) {
        return scan.nextInt();
    }
    return <Whatever your fallback is>;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by fallback?

Comment: You may want to check `if (scan.hasNextInt())` in the `if` before returning.

Comment: With *fallback* I mean a value to return in case your Scanner gets no numeric input at all.

Comment: It's not necessary to check for `scan.hasNextInt()` as if the while loop will exit with a remaining next token it will be int parsable due to the while condition.

Answer (score 0):

What will this code

```
while (!scan.hasNextInt()) {
    scan.next();
}
```

do when you pass it "a b c"?

It will go

- "a" is not an `int`, get the next token
- "b" is not an `int`, get the next token
- "c" is not an `int`, get the next token
- There's no more token left, throw a `NoSuchElementException`.